# Windows cannot access my external harddisk partition not responding

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I'm currently having problem with my External HDD Partitions
OS : Windows 8 64 bit.

I plugged in my laptop USB port and my laptop recognized the HDD
and this is what I sees in "My Computer"

So here's the problem, After plug in my External HDD, my laptop detected 2 partitions
Which is, E:/ and F:/ 
But I can't access my F:/ partitions, when I double click or right or try to do anything with it, I get not responding anymore!

[image]

Even I try to open ANY HDD Check Programs or anything, Nothing will respond until I plug out my External HDD from my laptop.

I tried enter into Command Prompt at start up and do "chkdsk F: /f /x /r" 
It took fews hours, and after I log back into my PC it still same.
This is what I tried, before start up, if I do it in Windows, it wont scan, its just stuck,
till i remove my external HDD.

[image]

Can anyone help me with this? All of my Data is in that F: partition :(

Comment: Disk looks pretty dead. Some file recovery may be possible (search site for answers to that effect. I favour `findntfs` and `findpart` tools, but GUI tools available too). Consider using SMART tools to detect imminent disk failure. Remember to make backups of your data - especially on an external drive that presumably gets moved around. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

From that last screenshot it looks like your disk is dying.
`Adding 1558 bad clusters to Bad Clusters File` is something to seriously worry about.
Considering the last message `failed to transfer logged messages to the event log with status 50`, it can mean several things. But the bad clusters are probably the cause.

I think your [MFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Internals) is corrupt and maybe some other parts too.
In the past I had the same kind of issue with an external harddrive.
I executed the following command line `chkdsk /F X:` (where X is the drive letter) about 120 times before it was fixed completely and I only lost 4 files (instead of 1.2 million). This may sound pretty weird but not trying is getting you nowhere either. And since you have bad clusters you might also want to try `chkdsk /R X:` or `chkdsk /B X:`.

Moreover to prevent more data loss buy a new drive, and when plugging it out, use the 'eject' option, it is there for a reason. People who say that function is useless were lucky enough to not experience data corruption (yet).

Comment: I tried it. It stuck here.
http://i1328.photobucket.com/albums/w531/OmgKarin/Fixxxx_zpsf5dca288.png

Comment: Try it at system start-up.

Comment: Ok, gonna try that now, and let you know!

Comment: I have tried chkdsk /f F:   Doesn't work still, so now im trying with chkdsk /r F: but im stuck at stage 5 of 5, 10 percent complete. <86007 of 97435536 free clusters processed> for the pass 20-30mins :(

Comment: Chkdsk can take days on large and damaged disk to complete, you have to be patient. Because of parameter '/r' it is trying to fix the data of bad clusters, which can take some time. If you cannot wait that long you can also try to use a data recovery tool, browse the web there are plenty of them.

Comment: Ohh, yeah, i have a lot of big files in there, and Data Recovery Tool doesn't work, like i mentioned above, that any disk tool as long as my external hdd plugged in, it wont launch up until i disconnect it. So this is the only way of doing it, 1 hour and still stuck at 86007 of 97435536. Guess just have to wait.

Comment: This is what I get when I use CMD at start up and scan, 
http://i1328.photobucket.com/albums/w531/OmgKarin/photo1_zps78bf1c6b.jpg , this is with chkdsk /f F: , But when I go back to windows, doesnt work, 
So I tried using this chkdsk /r F: , it stuck at 86007 of 97435536 for few hours, so i tried randomly Hit ENTER once, and it starting moving again till 100% complete, and still doesnt work when I go back to windows :( 
http://i1328.photobucket.com/albums/w531/OmgKarin/photo2_zps641c31f2.jpg

Comment: As long as the chkdsk tells you `Windows has made corrections...` or `Adding x bad clusters...` or `Failed to transfer...` you have to keep checking your disk, it means there is still stuff to clean up. Beyond that I cannot help you any further.

Comment: Now i'm currently trying with chkdsk /b F: , but what does this do?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730714.aspx

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the link, so i guess if this doesn't fix, I have to keep doing chkdsk /b F: right ?

Comment: I tried each of the command, still doesn't work :(
Do i have to keep scanning or ?

Comment: This will be my last comment on this question since this is getting a conversation instead of comments. I told you what to do , as long as you get errors keep scanning. If you have the impression it doesn't work, then there is nothing else I know of you can do. You could also ask another more detailed new question.